# Mostrar registro con el valor de cantidad más alto - MySql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un query que me trae los registros de una tabla y suma la cantidad de aquellos que tengan el mismo NUM_ART. Sin embargo quiero que me regrese el registro con el valor de la cantidad mas alta. El query que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
    SELECT NUMERO_ART, DESCRIPCION, SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD 
FROM DETALLE_DEL_PEDIDO D 
JOIN ARTxDIS ON D.ID_ARTxDIS = ARTxDIS.ID 
JOIN ARTICULOS ON ARTxDIS.NUMERO_ART = ARTICULOS.NUMERO
GROUP BY NUMERO_ART, DESCRIPCION
HAVING MAX(CANTIDAD);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si existe un metodo para hacer un filtro y obtener solo el registro con mas cantidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me dio el mismo resultado sin necesidad de colocar el HAVING

```
SELECT NUMERO_ART, DESCRIPCION, SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD 
FROM DETALLE_DEL_PEDIDO D 
JOIN ARTxDIS ON D.ID_ARTxDIS = ARTxDIS.ID 
JOIN ARTICULOS ON ARTxDIS.NUMERO_ART = ARTICULOS.NUMERO
GROUP BY NUMERO_ART, DESCRIPCION ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones que tienes es ordenar por cantidad y quedarte con el primer resultado:

```
SELECT NUMERO_ART, DESCRIPCION, SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD 
FROM DETALLE_DEL_PEDIDO D 
JOIN ARTxDIS ON D.ID_ARTxDIS = ARTxDIS.ID 
JOIN ARTICULOS ON ARTxDIS.NUMERO_ART = ARTICULOS.NUMERO
GROUP BY NUMERO_ART, DESCRIPCION
ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Como bien ha apuntado Luis, el having en este caso es innecesario